# Why use Auth::check() if Auth::user() retrieves already authenticated user or null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Just to clarify the question, are the following statements equivalent, or am I missing something and introducing a security hole?

```
// 1
if(Auth::user()){
    // do something
}

// 2
if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a quick peek under the hood

```
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

So as you can see, all that check does, is check for null. Using `Auth::check()` is much easier when all you need to know if whether they are auth'd. It would make no sense to return an object if you're not going to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if you intend to use `$user` object?

Comment: Then you probably want to assign `$user = Auth::user()` or you can just call the attribute you want such as the id of the user `Auth::user()->id`

Answer (score 0):

the statement Auth::Check() just returns if user is logged in or not.

Auth::user() returns the user that's logged in, if have one.

```
$user_name = Auth::user()->name;
```

and you can retrieve user's data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was asking if the if statements above were equivalent